# How do I access a port once I forward it?

Tags: ubuntu, port-forwarding

I think I have successfully forwarded my port for my Ubuntu server but now I am unsure how to access it.

Comment: Hello user1328147, welcome to SU.  There is almost no information in this question that will permit anyone to help you.  Please explain why you are forwarding a port, what you want to accomplish, and what protocol (tcp or udp) the port is, and what application you want to be accessible from the internet.

Comment: Short answer: You don't, other people do.

Comment: @David: Well, he _could_ be trying to access a forwarded port on his home router from work. Or he could be referring to an SSH tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

Configure your client to access the **external** IP-address of your **router** (and the external port number if you have also used Port Address Translation)

Your router will then forward packets to the internal address of your Ubuntu server (and to whatever port number on that server you specified in the router port-forwarding configuration)